# Sorting an array alphabetically in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Hope someone can help.
I have created a variable length array that will accept several name inputs.
I now want to sort the array in alphabetical order and return that to the console screen.

I thought that Array.Sort(names); would do this for me but I am getting an exception thrown. I have been looking at notes, examples and on-line but nothing seems to match what I am doing.

I have done the below so far. I am close to tearing my hair out here!
PS I have been trying to figure this out for hours and I am 30+ years old trying to learn myself, so please don't just say "Do your homework" I have tried to resolve this and can not so I need someone to explain where I am going wrong.
It is a Sunday and I am trying to do extra work and have no notes to cover this exactly

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace Student_Array
    {
        class Program
        {
            struct Student
            {
                public string Name;
            }
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int numberOfStudents;
                Student[] names;
                string input;
    
                Console.WriteLine("How many students are there?");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                numberOfStudents = int.Parse(input);
    
                names = new Student[numberOfStudents];
                
    
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    Student s;
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter student {0}'s name", (i + 1));
                    s.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                    names[i] = s;
                }
                ***Array.Sort<Student>(names);***
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                   
                    Console.WriteLine(names[i].Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This shall do the trick

```
Array.Sort(names, (x,y) => String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

Comment: Apologies, I marked as the answer but never replied with Thank You. That was perfect

Answer (score 7):

Your issue here might be that you are confusing the notions of students and names. By defining the `Student` struct, you are creating an entity that can represent more than a mere name. You could, for example, extend it to include `Age`, `Hometown`, and so forth. (For this reason, it might be more meaningful to name your array `students` rather than `names`.)

```
struct Student
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public string Hometown;
}
```

Given the possibility of multiple fields, the `Array.Sort` method needs to know what you want to sort your list upon. Do you want students ordered by name, by age, or by hometown?

Per the MSDN documentation on [`Array.Sort<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4.aspx):

> Sorts the elements in an entire `Array` using the `IComparable<T>` generic interface implementation of each element of the Array.

This means that the type you are attempting to sort – in your case, `Student` – must implement the [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) interface, in order for the `Array.Sort` implementation to know how it should compare two `Student` instances. If you're convinced that students will always be sorted by name, you could implement it like so:

```
struct Student : IComparable<Student>
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public string Hometown;

    public int CompareTo(Student other)
    {
        return String.Compare(this.Name, other.Name);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could provide a function that extracts the sort key to the sort method itself. The easiest way of achieving this is through the LINQ `OrderBy` method:

```
names = names.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: Right, and how does he sort it? Not an answer.

Comment: @ newStackExchangeInstance: Of course it's an answer. If he implements IComparable, his problem is solved by calling Array.Sort.

Answer (score 5):

You can either use `Sort` as is if you *extend Student to implement IComparable*;

```
    struct Student : IComparable<Student>
    {
        public string Name;
        public int CompareTo(Student other)
        {
            return String.Compare(Name, other.Name,
                   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
```

...or you can pass a compare lambda into Sort...

```
Array.Sort<Student>(names, (x, y) => String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name,
                                     StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

...or as a third option just create a new, sorted, array;

```
var newArray = names.OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToLower()).ToArray();
```

Comment: For the last one, maybe sorting by `x => x.Name.ToLower()` can be suggested

Comment: @JordanTrudgett Ah, yes, missed that last part :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well, instead of using Array.Sort.

```
names = names.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a comparer class

```
class StudentComparer : IComparer<Student>
{
    public int Compare(Student a, Student b)
    {
        return a.Name.CompareTo(b.Name);
    }
}
```

Sort:

```
Array.Sort(students,new StudentComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort by the `name` property of your `Student` objects in your `Student` array, you can use

```
Array.Sort(names, (s1, s2) => String.Compare(s1.Name, s2.Name));
```

which will sort your array in place, or with `System.Linq`:

```
names = names.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToArray();
```

which can return the sorted `IEnumerable` as an array (`.ToArray()`) or a list (`.ToList()`.)

Remember to sort case-insensitive if it matters, as pointed out in another answer, which can be done in `String.Compare` like so:

```
String.Compare(s1.Name, s2.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score -4):

you can find one of the basics algorithms here : [Simple bubble sort c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768010/simple-bubble-sort-c-sharp)

you have to do some modifications , that example is for int, for string you must compare the names.

you can find better algorithms for sorting. for now bubble sort is ok for you.

Comment: -1 for not giving an answer, but refering to other links or some phrases which are, for the OP, not a concrete answer.