# How to sort a list of objects by property using Bubble sort C#

Tags: c#, sorting, object

I searched an answer for my question but I could not find anything. I am sorry if there is a similar theme.
So I need to sort a list of objects by their property and I have to use bubble sort. How can I make it without using methods like "list.sort". 
Thank you in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Animals
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("How much animals you want to add?: ");
        int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var newAnimals = new List<Animals>(count);
        Animals animal = new Animals();
        newAnimals.Add(animal);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            newAnimals[i].id = i;
            Console.Write("Write name for animal:  " + i + ": ");

            newAnimals[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Write age for animal:  " + i + ": ");

            newAnimals[i].age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Write color for animal:  " + i + ": ");

            newAnimals[i].color = Console.ReadLine();
            newAnimals.Add(new Animals() { id = 1, name = "name" });
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Name \tAge \tColor");

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newAnimals[i].name + "\t" + newAnimals[i].age + "\t" + newAnimals[i].color);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
               Console.WriteLine("Name \tAge \tColor");

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(newAnimals[i].name + "\t" + newAnimals[i].age + "\t" + newAnimals[i].color);
             }


            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple bubble sort c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768010/simple-bubble-sort-c-sharp)

Comment: Have you even tried one of the given answers?

Answer (score 2):

Generic, with dynamic property selector :

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void BubbleSort<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, int> selector)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bool changed = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (selector(list[i - 1]) > selector(list[i]))
                {
                    T temp = list[i - 1];
                    list[i - 1] = list[i];
                    list[i] = temp;
                    changed = true;
                }
            }

            if (!changed)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
unsortedList.BubbleSort(x => x.SortProperty);
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go (assuming that you want to sort by id)

```
for (int i = 0; i < newAnimals.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (newAnimals[j - 1].id > newAnimals[j].id)
        {
            Animals temp = newAnimals[j - 1];
            newAnimals[j - 1] = newAnimals[j];
            newAnimals[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```