# C# What is the advantage of using interfaces for simulating multiple inheritance?

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance

Interfaces are a feature of C# that I've never quite been able to see the purpose of. I see them used all the time in professional code, but for the life of me I can't work out the reasoning.

My question here is specifically about interfaces to simulate multiple inheritance. In reading around the subject, I'll often come up on an example like this:

```
interface IAddition
{
    int add(int a, int b);
}

interface ISubtraction
{
    int sub(int a, int b);
}

class Calculation : IAddition, ISubtraction
{        
    public int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return result1 = a + b;
    }

    public int sub(int a, int b)
    {
        return result1 = a - b;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is - what benefit do the interfaces bring here? It looks to me like you could remove them completely, and the Calculation class would still work exactly the same. What am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated - I've been looking for something to make interfaces 'click' in my head for quite a while now.

It's worth noting I'm a game developer, and I'm looking for a solution for this to improve my ability to develop games, but I thought that it was a general enough question to post here.

Comment: To me this looks like a rather poor example. I suggest to go and either find better tutorials or simply study the Interfecs in the .NET framework. As a SO question it is no longer on-topic though.

Comment: Look at the framework interfaces e.g. `public class HashSet<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback, ISet<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Often a collection will implement multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right. The code will still compile after you remove the interfaces. So why add them?

Well, your `IAddition` and `ISubtraction` examples aren't really good to make my point here. Since the best way to learn programming is to look at how other people code, I'll use the `System.IComparable<T>` interface as an example. It is an interface provided by the .NET framework.

The reason why we use interfaces is to achieve *polymorphism*. Interfaces are like protocols which classes must conform to. If a class implements an interface, it is guaranteed that the class can do the things that the interface specifies. This all sounds quite confusing so let's take a look at the `IComparable<T>` interface. To make things simpler, let's make it `IComparable<int>`

`IComparable<int>` has this method:

```
int CompareTo(int other);
```

This basically means

> Everything that implements `IComparable<int>` *has the ability* to be compared with an integer. We can call its `CompareTo` method to decide whether it is bigger than, equal to, or less than any `int`.

Since everything that implemets `IComparable<int>` must have the method `CompareTo`, it is guaranteed that the object you're calling `CompareTo` on can be compared with an `int`.

So how is this useful?

The ability to be compared with something else is useful when you sort arrays. The `Array.Sort` method make use of the `IComparable<T>` interface. Here's how the `Sort` method works (highly simplified):

It first checks whether the array's elements can be compared by checking whether they implement `IComparable<T>`. If they do, compare them by calling `CompareTo`! Why can it be so sure that there is a method called `CompareTo`? Because the objects all implement `IComparable<T>`, which guarantees a `CompareTo` method! After comparing, `Sort` can figure out which element comes first and last.

You see how different things need to be compared differently? Integers and `double`s can be compared by subtracting one from the other and checking whether the result is a positive or negative number. But strings are compared alphabetically. If there weren't a `IComparable<T>` interface, there would have been a different `Sort` method for strings, and a `Sort` method for `int`, and a `Sort` method for all the types that can be compared. Worse, if client code creates something that can be compared, the client code needs to write its own `Sort` method! Don't forget that there are a ton of other methods that make use of the ability to be compared. Do all *those* methods need a different version for each type?

That's why interfaces are so important. With them, only one `Sort` method is needed because polymorphism takes care of the rest.

Let me summarise the advantages of interfaces:

- It provides flexibility (integers and strings can both be compared to integers and strings, but in different ways)
- It reduces code (You don't need to write extra `Sort` methods!)
- It ensures safety (If you forgot to implement a method, the compiler will tell you!)

Let's assume that `IComparable<T>` does not exist, and `string` and `int` and other types that can be compared as their own `CompareTo` method. The `Sort` methods can look like this

```
public static void Sort(int[] arr) {
    // note that I'm using bubble sort here. A real sort method wouldn't use this coz it's slow.
    // source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768010/simple-bubble-sort-c-sharp
    int temp = 0;

    for (int write = 0; write < arr.Length; write++) {
        for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++) {
            if (arr[sort].CompareTo(arr[sort + 1]) > 0) {
                temp = arr[sort + 1];
                arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                arr[sort] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void Sort(string[] arr) {
    string temp = 0;

    for (int write = 0; write < arr.Length; write++) {
        for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++) {
            if (arr[sort].CompareTo(arr[sort + 1]) > 0) {
                temp = arr[sort + 1];
                arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                arr[sort] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You could argue that one `Sort` method that takes an `object[]` checks the type of each element could also work. Yes, but that suffers from the same problem as multiple `Sort` methods. You still need to add another sort method or another check if a new comparable class is created.

The problem all end if you have a `IComparable<T>` interface!

```
public static void Sort<T>(T[] arr) where T : IComparable<T> {
    T temp;

    for (int write = 0; write < arr.Length; write++) {
        for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++) {
            if (arr[sort].CompareTo(arr[sort + 1]) > 0) {
                temp = arr[sort + 1];
                arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                arr[sort] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the type constraint says that `T` must implement `IComparable<T>`, `CompareTo` can be called on every object in the array with no problems!

Now all you need to do if you wish to add another comparable class is to implement the interface. Whereas if the interface didn't exist, you have to write a `CompareTo` method *and* a `Sort` method!

Comment: This is a really nice answer that is very helpful. I'm starting to get my head around it! However, I'm not quite sure I understand how it reduces code. If you can't actually write any implementation of a method within an interface, how can it reduce the code? Don't you still need to write the various sort methods? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Oh oops! I meant "duplicate code". With interfaces, you just need one CompareTo method for each class that can be compared, which is far better than to see than 10+ Sort methods that you can call when you want to sort an array. @Infergnome

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm experiencing a mental block with this. Could you perhaps provide a little snippet of code to show the different implementations of Sort? (one with interfaces, one without)? That would be so helpful.

Comment: @Infergnome Edited

Comment: Thank you so much! My mental block has been @Sweeper'ed away! (excuse the pun)

Answer (score 1):

[See this msdn article for details ("No Multiple-Inheritance in .NET" section)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973861.aspx):

Interfaces address the problem of multiple-inheritance, which is not allowed to prevent ambiguity in the compiler when it is trying to find the correct implementation. In their example BabyBasset inherits Hound and Puppy, but say both of those classes provided the implementation of a method called "Bark()", which one would be executed? Hence the ambiguity.

Classes can implement multiple interfaces, and where there is ambiguity (i.e. two methods in seperate interfaces with the same name) they can be explicitly implemented in the class, thus removing the ambiguity.

Comment: _"Interfaces address the problem of multiple-inheritance"_ - is only a very small part of what/why interfaces are.

Comment: I fully agree, @HenkHolterman, but it was clear from the question that the questioner understood the basic concepts of interfaces, but was struggling to distinguish their use from class inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are a contract that an object will have certain members that provide specific functionality.

This allows you to provide a level of abstraction such that code can be written to work with interfaces rather than classes.

For example, I might have a class that inherits the IList interface. There could be any number of implementations that simply store a list of 'things'. Under the covers it doesn't matter to me what the implementation is, all I might care about is that they include the `Add()` and `GetEnumerator()` so I can add things and loop over them. It's up to the implementer of the class inheriting the interface to provide the implementation.

Multiple inheritance is usually done so that you can split up functionality. You may have a class that does subtraction, addition or both. The code calling the methods on an object that inherits the addition interface doesn't care about anything other than the members that provide the addition functionality. Same with code using a class that inherits the subtraction interface. It then allows you or someone else to replace those classes with something else and as long as they implement the interface the consumer doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is basically a contract between you and your client, like enforcement it forces that your client must has to implement the method which are declared in the interface.

Lets take you code as example.

```
interface IAddition
{
    int add(int a, int b);
}

interface ISubtraction
{
    int sub(int a, int b);
}

class Calculation : IAddition, ISubtraction
{

}
```

So If you dont implement `Add` and `Sub` methods, compiler will give you error. And If you remove your interfaces, there is no contract, so noboday checks about your class implementation. You do whatever you want to do.

Multiple Inheritance is allowed and it has good significance in multiple scenarios. you class can have multiple contracts with others interfaces. Example you have 1 interface, 10 different interfaces are implementing this interface. So some of the class can implement the top most interface, else some can implement 1,2,5 interfaces depending on their individual functionality.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a binding contract that guarantees your classes will implement some feature. The more interfaces a class uses the more features is advertised to use.

Think of interfaces like cereal box labels. If it says "no sugar added" you can be fairly certain your cereal (or your class) doesn't have any sugar added.

In your example `IAdd` and `ISub` are advertizing that you class knows how to perform certain operations. It is up to you to decide to what fine grain level you want the features of your class to be split up in one or more interfaces or not. It all depends to future usage. If you have an interface that is only used by one class, then maybe that interface is not really needed.