# What's wrong with my MergeSort? C#

Tags: c#, mergesort

To keep it short. I made a MergeSort, which should sort an `int[]`. To test the MergeSort I made an array containing 4 `integers` in random order. It returns the exact list in the order given to the MergeSort, instead of doing what it should do. I wonder what I did wrong.

Edit: The first two merges return these two lists: 4, 15 && 5, 16, however the last merge doesn't work.

This is the actual code:

```
 public static int[] Merge(int[] list, int left, int mid, int right)
    {
        int[] returnList = new int[list.Length];
        int Index = left;

        //last value of left half
        int leftEnd = mid;

        //both the left side and right side contain atleast one value
        while (leftEnd >= left && right >= (mid + 1))
        {
            if (list[left] <= list[(mid + 1)])
            {
                returnList[Index] = list[left];
                left++;
            }
            else
            {
                returnList[Index] = list[(mid + 1)];
                mid++;
            }
            Index++;
        }

        //right side is empty, left contains atleast one value
        while (leftEnd >= left)
        {
            returnList[Index] = list[left];
            left++;
            Index++;
        }

        //left side is empty, right contains atleast one value
        while (right >= (mid + 1))
        {
            returnList[Index] = list[(mid + 1)];
            mid++;
            Index++;
        }

        return returnList;
    }

    public static int[] Split(int[] list, int left, int right)
    {
        if (right > left)
        {
            int mid = (right + left) / 2;

            Split(list, left, mid); //first half
            Split(list, (mid + 1), right); //second half
            list = Merge(list, left, (mid + 1), right);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

My Main:

```
        int[] intArray = new int[] { 12, 4, 16, 5 };
        int[] ReturnTest = MergeSort.Split(intArray, 0, intArray.Length - 1);

        foreach (int value in ReturnTest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
```

The expected output: 4, 5, 12, 16

The actual output: 12, 4, 16, 5

Comment: What wrong with `Array.Sort(intArray);` ?

Comment: I'm a college student and we've been asked to write a MergeSort ourselves.

Comment: You did not give the expected and actual output.

Comment: @M.Mayhem Ah ok :-) , there is no shame in mentioning that. Otherwise I would already bet, some will say "don't reinvent the wheel" ;-)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ - As a student this is an excellent opportunity for you to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe the runtime behavior and variable values.  There you can determine exactly where the behavior deviates from what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! And will try, @David!

Comment: How about a good old bubble sort? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768010/simple-bubble-sort-c-sharp

Comment: @David I tried the MergeSort with an array of 4 numbers, however in the 3rd merge (the final merge) the list is not the array of the the first 2 merges merged together, but the actual starting input array. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @M.Mayhem does not the referred article answer that question though? Just use a debugger and step through your code.