# How to sort and remove duplicates from string Array without using the inbuilt function?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I want to remove duplicate string also sort the string array in `C#` I am reading text file which contains data like Blue, Green, Red, Green, Yellow so I am reading data using `File.ReadAllLines()` which return an array of string now how to sort and remove duplicate.

```
private string[] sortArray(string[] str)
{
    int cnt = str.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        for (int j = cnt; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (((IComparable)str[j - 1]).CompareTo(str[j]) > 0)
            {
                var temp = str[j - 1];
                str[j - 1] = str[j];
                str[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

using this above code I can sort the array but how to remove the duplicate string
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Bubble sort, seriously? Aby reason for not using inbuilt methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple bubble sort c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768010/simple-bubble-sort-c-sharp)

Comment: @Max : this code can also sort but how to remove duplicate from this using this same loop

Comment: @IvanStoev : do you have any simple solution which gives fastest sort and remove duplicate

Comment: As you already able to sort it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-c-sharp-array) to remove duplicates

Comment: @Bhaginath : i want remove duplicate also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677/8505315)

Comment: A simple search found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp) on how remove an element from array

Comment: Sure. For instance, Instead of `File.ReadAllLines()`, use `File.ReadLines()` + LINQ, e.g. `ReadLines().Disttinc().OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();`. Of course there are many other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Here is what you can do

```
List<string> colorList = new List<string> { "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Yellow" };
colorList = colorList.Distinct().OrderBy(item=> item).ToList();
```

`File.ReadAllLines()` will give you `string[]` and you can apply **Dictinct** and **OrderBy** in the same way as mentioned above

### Sorting & remove duplicate without using build-in functions

Create a call to methods like this

```
string[] colorArray = new string[] { "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Yellow" };
colorArray = RemoveDuplicates(colorArray);
Sort(colorArray);
```

sort using below method

```
static void Sort(string[] sa)
{
    int pos = 1;
    while (pos < sa.Length)
    {
        if (String.Compare(sa[pos], sa[pos - 1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            pos++;
        }
        else
        {
            string temp = sa[pos];
            sa[pos] = sa[pos - 1];
            sa[pos - 1] = temp;
            if (pos > 1) pos--;
        }
    }
}
```

Remove duplicates using this one

```
static string[] RemoveDuplicates(string[] inputArray)
{

    int length = inputArray.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < length;)
        {
            if (inputArray[i] == inputArray[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < length - 1; k++)
                    inputArray[k] = inputArray[k + 1];
                length--;
            }
            else
                j++;
        }
    }

    string[] distinctArray = new string[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        distinctArray[i] = inputArray[i];

    return distinctArray;

}
```

Comment: without using inbuilt functions want to sort and remove duplicates from array string

Comment: @ketanpatil, try the mentioned code above. This is without build-in fucntions.

Answer (score 1):

We can remove duplicate items using below code. In below code
instead stack you can use any collection like List, Dictionary and etc. That supports contains function. Using any existing sorting algorithm you can sort the items

```
string[] colorArray = new string[] { "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Yellow" };
        Stack<string> strStacks = new Stack<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < colorArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (strStacks.Contains(colorArray[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                strStacks.Push(colorArray[i]);
            }
        }
```